# Repeatedly collect data from a website using R, Python or C

Tags: web-crawler

I am not sure whether this question is appropriate for this site since I am completely new to this. But I will ask anyway. By the way, normally I use R. Python and C are also manageable.

The situation is this, I need to download data from a website repeatedly. Each time the following step is taken:

1. Enter a date to a cell on that website.
2. If no error occurs, then click a button on that website to generate required data. Then click another button to save the data in a spreadsheet.
3. If error does occur, usually that date is not a trading date, then select the next date until no error occurs.

I need to do so for all trading days in the past 3 years. Is there a way to do so, please? Any hands-on reference to this type of problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In which language?

I've done something like that in python with pyGhost, but is a little buggy...

Also Selenium lets you make an script or program to automate your 'tests' and you can use it to achieve your goal. It works with many languages, I would go with it...

https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Example+Selenium+Scripts+for+Automated+Website+Tests

and

https://www.mkyong.com/selenium/how-to-execute-javascript-in-selenium-webdriver/

Could be a good starting points.